# Hibernate: Deleting in One-to-Many/Many-To-One fails

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, one-to-many

Let's say we have three entities: `Course`,`Student` and `Guide`.
Many Students can visit many courses and many courses can contain many students.That's why I have created a `bidirectional Many-To-Many`-Relationship between `Student` and `Course`:

```
@Entity()
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString(exclude = "courses")
@Builder
@Table(name = "students")
public class Student {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "courses_students",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "students_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "courses_id"))
    private Set<Course> courses;


}
```

```
@Entity
@Builder
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString(exclude = "guide")
@Table(name="courses")
public class Course {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name="guide_id")
    private Guide guide;

    @Column
    private String title;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "courses")
    Set<Student> students;
}
```

Furthermore there are for each course only one guide, but one guide can teach in several courses. So there is a `birectional One-to-Many` / `Many-to-One`-Relationship between `Course` and `Guide` with the Ownership at the side of the `Course`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "guides")
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
public class Guide {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "guide")
    private List<Course> courses = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

When I delete all Students, by `Cascade.Remove` all `Course`-entities are also removed, which is fine. But I am getting a list of courses when I retrieve `Guide`-instances from the `GuideRepository` and call `<guideInstance>.getCourses()`. I would expect an empty list, because from the `CourseRepository` I get nothing! What is here the problem?

To reproduce that problem, I post the code for the creation of the entities:

```
 Course java= Course.builder().title("Java").build();
    Course python= Course.builder().title("Python").build();
    Course kotlin= Course.builder().title("Kotlin").build();

    Set<Course> johnCourses=new HashSet<>();
    johnCourses.add(java);
    johnCourses.add(python);

    Set<Course> jackCourses=new HashSet<>();
    jackCourses.add(java);
    jackCourses.add(python);
    jackCourses.add(kotlin);

    Set<Course> henryCourses=new HashSet<>();
    henryCourses.add(python);
    henryCourses.add(kotlin);

    List<Course> drMorrisCourses=new ArrayList<Course>();
    drMorrisCourses.add(java);
    drMorrisCourses.add(kotlin);

    List<Course> drFerrisCourses=new ArrayList<Course>();
    drFerrisCourses.add(python);

    Guide drMorris = Guide.builder().name("Dr. Morris").courses(drMorrisCourses).build();
    Guide drFerris = Guide.builder().name("Dr. Ferris").courses(drFerrisCourses).build();

    Student john= Student.builder().name("John").courses(johnCourses).build();
    Student jack= Student.builder().name("Jack").courses(jackCourses).build();
    Student henry= Student.builder().name("Henry").courses(henryCourses).build();

    Set<Student> javaStudents=new HashSet<>();
    javaStudents.add(john);
    javaStudents.add(jack);

    Set<Student> kotlinStudents=new HashSet<>();
    kotlinStudents.add(jack);
    kotlinStudents.add(henry);

    Set<Student> pythonStudents=new HashSet<>();
    pythonStudents.add(john);
    pythonStudents.add(henry);
    pythonStudents.add(jack);

    java.setGuide(drMorris);
    kotlin.setGuide(drMorris);
    python.setGuide(drFerris);

    java.setStudents(javaStudents);
    python.setStudents(pythonStudents);
    kotlin.setStudents(kotlinStudents);

    studentRepository.save(john);
    studentRepository.save(jack);
    studentRepository.save(henry);

    courseRepository.save(java);
    courseRepository.save(kotlin);
    courseRepository.save(python);

    guideRepository.save(drMorris);
    guideRepository.save(drFerris);
```

Now all Entities are set. To delete one student I can use for example following code:

```
      List<Student> allStudents = studentRepository.findAll();
//Here I choose for example first student and delete it!        
studentrepository.delete(allStudents.get(0));
```

I deleted the first `Student`-Entity, that means `John`, which visits the `Java` course. With the deletion of `John` the `Java` course is also gone, because of `Cascase.REMOVE`:

```
List<Course> courses =courseRepository.findAll();
courses.size() // -> only 2 because Java course entity is deleted!!!!
```

But if I call the first guide entity, that means `drMorris` I can see that `drMorris` still have the `Java` course, although `Java` course-Entity is deleted!:

```
List<Guide> guides=guideRepository.findAll();
guides.get(0).getCourses //<- drMorris should not have Java Course!!!!!!!!
```

Comment: We don't know, because you didn't post the code that reproduces the problem. But using cascade=REMOVE on a ManyToXxx association is always a bad idea. If I delete the student John, then all of the courses that John visits shouldn't be deleted: Jane, Jack and Henry also visit that course, so if you have correct foreign key constraints in your database, that's guaranteed to fail with an exception anyway.

Comment: but your codes does not show how you delete the student ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution:

```
   public void deleteStudents(){
        List<Student> all = studentRepository.findAll();
       deleteStudent(all.get(2));
     }

     public void deleteStudent(Student student) {

        Set<Course> courses = student.getCourses();

         for (Course course: courses) {
             if (course.getStudents().size() == 1 ){
                 course.getGuide().getCourses().remove(course);

                 courseRepository.delete(course);
             } else {
                 course.getStudents().remove(student);
             }
         }
         studentRepository.delete(student);
    }
```